# JArray(Json.net) multiple thread access causing "Collection was modified"

Tags: c#

I am using async IO to read a file and compute hashes(using multiple threads) of the file chunks and store into a JArray. Before reading i created JArray with the number of chunks and the threads will keep on updating the JArray with the hash.I need to find out whether the array does not have any nulls which indicates the file read has been completed.

```
var t = j.Children().Where(s => (s.Type == JTokenType.Null));
count = t.Count();
```

I am getting an exception

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

is there any way to get the count atomically independent of the threads.

I am using c# Threadpool to process the data.

```
FileTransferThreadPool fftp = new FileTransferThreadPool();
ResultData rd = new ResultData(aol, data, hash);
fftp.Queue(rd);

public FileTransferThreadPool(int threadpoolsize = 2)
{
    public bool Queue(ResultData rd){
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(ThreadProc), rd);
        return true;
    }

    static void ThreadProc(Object stateInfo)
    {
        JObject jo = aol.root;
        JArray j = (JArray)jo["hash"];
        j[(int)aol.number] = hash;
        var te = j.Children().Where(s => (s.Type == JTokenType.Null));
        count = te.Count();
    }
}
```

Comment: most linq function use deferred excution, so if something change source collection after calling `Where` but before or intime materialize, you get this error. Can you provide a bit more code how you use it?

Comment: @Grundy: I have updated code in my post, please have a look. Thanks